# How to implement 'playhead' kind of feature on a simple graph?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- I have a simple plot of x vs y data plotted using Pyqtgraph
- Overlaid on this graph I would like to have a 'playhead' kind of line bar that moves through the x axis (similar to timeline scrubber in video editors)
- The position of this line on the x-axis should be dynamically received from a callback function

Please have a look into the picture below for clear understanding.

[image: link]

Comment: Do you want it to move automatically(like scanning all the plot)? or manually?

Comment: The position of the line should change based on the input(which corresponds exactly to the x axis value) it receives from an external function.. Is that clear? Please let me know if i haven't explained it well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an infinite vertical line object, this is part of `pyqtgraph`: `InfiniteLine`.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
v_line = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=True)
```

This object has the property to be movable by drag, and each time you move the line it emits a signal: `sigPositionChanged`. You can connect this signal with a function that returns the value of its position, or the nearest x-value of your data and its corresponding y-value.

```py
v_line.sigPositionChanged.connect(some_function)
```

You said in your comment, that the position depends on input or the output of a function. Then you can change the position using the `setPos()` method of the `InfiniteLine` object.

```py
v_line.setPos(10)
```

Below is an example I did, you can guide from the code to get a better understanding.
In this example you can manually drag the vertical line, it can only be "placed" in the values of the x-data, and the x and y values will be shown in the boxes.

Also, you can change only the value of the box corresponding to the x-value and when you press Return/Enter key the position of the line will go to the nearest x-value in your data.

[image]

Here is the code:

```py
import sys 
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        lay_1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(lay_1)
        label_1 = QtGui.QLabel('Marker Value :  x = ')
        label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(', y = ')
        self.box_1 = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.box_1.setButtonSymbols(2)
        self.box_2 = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.box_2.setButtonSymbols(2)
        self.box_2.setReadOnly(True)
        spacer = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.graf = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plt = self.graf.plot()
        self.v_line = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=True)
        lay_1.addLayout(lay_2)
        lay_1.addWidget(self.graf)
        lay_2.addWidget(label_1)
        lay_2.addWidget(self.box_1)
        lay_2.addWidget(label_2)
        lay_2.addWidget(self.box_2)
        lay_2.addItem(spacer)
        self.graf.addItem(self.v_line)
        x = np.arange(100)/10*np.pi
        y = np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x/10)*10
        self.box_1.setRange(x.min(), x.max())
        self.box_2.setRange(y.min(), y.max())
        self.data = [x, y]
        self.plt.setData(*self.data)
        self.v_line.sigPositionChanged.connect(self.upd_drag)
        self.box_1.lineEdit().returnPressed.connect(self.box_edited)

    def get_xy(self, x_val):
        '''For filtering the position of the vertical lines, selecting
        limits and only prefered positions related to the x-data'''
        x_data = self.data[0]
        y_data = self.data[1]
        x_min = min(x_data)
        x_max = max(x_data)
        if x_val < x_min:
            x_val = x_min
        elif x_val > x_max: 
            x_val = x_max
        i = np.abs(x_data-x_val).argmin()
        x_val = x_data[i]
        y_val = y_data[i]
        return x_val, y_val

    def box_edited(self):
        pos = self.box_1.value()
        self.upd_v_line(pos)
        
    def upd_drag(self, line):
        pos = line.pos()[0]
        self.upd_v_line(pos)

    def upd_v_line(self, pos):
        x, y = self.get_xy(pos)
        self.v_line.setPos(x)
        self.box_1.setValue(x)
        self.box_2.setValue(y)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```